# Cordova phonertc demo working on android but not on browser

Tags: android, cordova, browser, webrtc, phonertc

I'm experimenting with the [phonertc cordova plugin](http://phonertc.io).
Any public demo wasn't working for me, so i've written one by my self, copying the structures of the examples of the original repository.

The demo is a simple audio call between two users that are using the app.
**When i run it on android it works fine**, i can talk to the other person, and **on the signaling server logs i can read the messages** that the library exchanges between the two clients.

But **when i run on the browser** (chrome or mozilla), i can see that the application logic works fine, but **the library, when calling**

```
session.call()
```

just **do not generate any error** message and the **signaling server receive nothing.** Just, the demo do not works on browser and i have no idea how to debug this.

All the project is [here on github](https://github.com/giosch/phonertc_demo) if you want to check for mistakes.
**What can i do to debug or solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

PhoneRTC is a cordova plugin, which means, It is a cordova based wrapper for the Android and iOS SDK's. Cordova plugins do not work in the browser as they wrap native SDKs meant to be used in the respective OS, in this case either android or iOS..